# Calculate time with cudaEvent_t

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to calculate time in c++ cuda program

But I received 0.000 for **timeProd** variable. 
(It can't be zero, because operation is not small)

**What I did wrong?**
 This line `cudaEventRecord(stopProd, 0);` returns error

> CUDA Error: Assign rnorm = d : 33 (invalid resource handle).

Me code

```
float timeProd;
  cudaEvent_t startProd, stopProd;
  cudaEventCreate(&startProd);
  cudaEventCreate(&stopProd);
  cudasafe(cudaEventRecord(startProd, 0), "Assign rnorm = d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
  //rr_dot_product.record_start();

  for (int i = 0; i < cudaGetDeviceCountVal; i++) {
    cudaSetDevice(i);
    gpu_dot(r[i], r[i], endGpu[i] - startGpu[i], buff[i], rho[i]);
  }
  cudasafe(cudaEventRecord(stopProd, 0), "Assign rnorm = d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
  cudasafe(cudaEventSynchronize(startProd), "Assign rnorm = d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
  cudasafe(cudaEventSynchronize(stopProd), "Assign rnorm = d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
  cudasafe(cudaEventElapsedTime(&timeProd, startProd, stopProd), "Assign rnorm = d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
  printf("timeProd %.20f\n", timeProd);
```

Comment: CUDA API functions return error codes. You generally wanna check the return value of every function for a potential error…what error do you get?

Comment: Updated question
Error: CUDA Error: Assign rnorm = d : 33 (invalid resource handle).

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: You cannot use events across devices as you are doing. Create events after the cudaSetDevice calls

Answer (score 1):

Events are tied to specific GPU and you need to ensure that the events only used with the device on which they are created. I would expect this modification to work:

```
  float timeProd;
  cudaEvent_t startProd, stopProd;
  cudaSetDevice(0); // Explicit device selection for event
  cudaEventCreate(&startProd);
  cudaEventCreate(&stopProd);
  cudasafe(cudaEventRecord(startProd, 0), "Assign rnorm = d", __FILE__, __LINE__);

  for (int i = 0; i < cudaGetDeviceCountVal; i++) {
    cudaSetDevice(i);
    gpu_dot(r[i], r[i], endGpu[i] - startGpu[i], buff[i], rho[i]);
  }

  cudaSetDevice(0); // Change back to device which owns event before continuing
  cudasafe(cudaEventRecord(stopProd, 0), "Assign rnorm = d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
  cudasafe(cudaEventSynchronize(startProd), "Assign rnorm = d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
  cudasafe(cudaEventSynchronize(stopProd), "Assign rnorm = d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
  cudasafe(cudaEventElapsedTime(&timeProd, startProd, stopProd), "Assign rnorm = d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
  printf("timeProd %.20f\n", timeProd);
```